# Trouble with stack.peek()?

Tags: java, stack, peek

This section of my code does not appear to be working. I feel like the problem might like with the stk.peek() sections of the code but I am not sure if this is true. Any ideas?

stk is my stack and the first thing read into the code is "("

```
if(stk.empty()==true || stk.peek()== "("){
    stk.push(post.get(i))      
    System.out.println("Test1:" +stk.peek());
}
```

Comment: The issue is that you're not comparing strings properly. Use `.equals()`, not `==`.

Comment: Why write `stk.empty()==true`? Surely `stk.empty()==(1 == 1)` would be more clear. Or, `stk.empty()== ((1 == 1) == (true != false))`?

Comment: @user3580294 What do you mean? I tried multiple variations of that
stk.equals('(')
stk.equals("(")
none seemed to work

Comment: @BoristheSpider Doesn't stk.empty() use a boolean? I thought that would be easier to write and look at.

Comment: @user2920249 That's because in those cases you're comparing *the stack* to `"("`, not `stk.peek()`. A stack is obviously not equal to a `String`. You want `stk.peek().equals("(")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. This should do it and has somewhat better style.

```
if (stk.empty() || "(".equals(stk.peek())){
    stk.push(post.get(i));     
    System.out.println("Test1:" + stk.peek());
}
```

Comment: This gets me a lot closer. It fixed this section of codes problems. I'm gonna try it on the others. Thank you so much.